# Throwing a C++ exception inside an omp critical section

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm wondering if it is safe to throw an C++ exception inside an OMP critical section.

```
#pragma omp critical (my_critical_section)
{
    ...
    throw my_exception("failed")
    ...       
}
```

g++ does not complain. I'm puzzled because it complains about `return` statements inside the critical section. It returns the error: `invalid exit from OpenMP structured block` when I write

```
#pragma omp critical (my_critical_section)
{
    ...
    return;
    ...       
}
```

So, why is it OK to leave the critical section with an exception, but it is **not** OK to leave it with a return statement?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it is not OK to leave a critical section with exceptions. `g++` does not complain in this case but it silently inserts an implicit `try/catch` around the block of the critical section. For example the following code:

```
#pragma omp critical (my_crit)
{
   throw 3;
}
```

gets lowered by the OpenMP processor of GCC 4.7 into:

```
#pragma omp critical (my_crit)
__builtin_GOMP_critical_name_start (&.gomp_critical_user_my_crit);
try
  {
    D.20639 = __cxa_allocate_exception (4);
    try
      {
        MEM[(int *)D.20639] = 3;
      }
    catch
      {
        __cxa_free_exception (D.20639);
      }
    __cxa_throw (D.20639, &_ZTIi, 0B);
  }
catch
  {
    <<<eh_must_not_throw (terminate)>>>
  }
__builtin_GOMP_critical_name_end (&.gomp_critical_user_my_crit);
```

Reaching the implicit built-in catch-all handler `<<<eh_must_not_throw (terminate)>>>` results in quite ungraceful termination:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Abort trap: 6
```

The implicit `try/catch` is inserted regardless of the presence of an outer `try/catch` construct, i.e. the exception would never ever leave the `critical` section.

The OpenMP standard mandates, that if an exception is thrown within most OpenMP constructs (`parallel`, `section`, `master`, `single`, `for`, `critical`, `task`, etc.), execution must resume within the same construct and that the same thread must catch the exception. Violation of this restriction leads to non-conformant OpenMP code and `g++` simply enforces the conformance by inserting `try/catch` blocks with termination handlers inside all such constructs.

As for the error when a `return` statement is present, OpenMP defines a strcutured block in C/C++ as:

> For C/C++, an executable statement, possibly compound, with a single entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom, or an OpenMP construct.

and also (for all languages):

> The point of exit cannot be a branch out of the *structured block*.

Obviously `return` constitutes a branch ouf of the block, different from simply falling of the bottom of the block.